# Excel Macro to connect to Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oledb, adodb, tns, ora-12541

I have below excel macro to connect to oracle database. But, one executing the code, I get the error message -

> "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': ORA-12541:TNS:no listener"

Please help me resolve this error message.

I have 'Oracle SQL Developer 3.2' installed on my pc.

```
Sub connectToCISDB()

Dim dbCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim recordSet As New ADODB.recordSet
Dim strQuery, strCon As String

strQuery = "select * from SAPSR3.eanlh;"

Set dbCon = New ADODB.Connection      
dbCon.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;User ID=xautotext;Password=F7_kxxxxZS;Data Source=ouxxpdxx1"
```

End Sub

Comment: What if you try to connect by SQLPLUS? If you get the same error, as I believe, the issue is in you DB / TNS file, ...

Comment: @Aleksej


Below is my TNSNAMES.ORA file content:
CIS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ouxxpdxx1)(PORT = 1526))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = [AUG])
    )
  )

Comment: @Aleksej
I am able to connect and query the db tables from Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Open a command prompt (Start - Execute - "cmd") and then type this command : `tnsping ouxxpdxx1`. What do you see ?

Comment: @ThomasG 
I get this message on cmd prompt - "'tnsping' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

Using the right connectionstring resolved the issue.

*Connection String*:
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};
Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=199.199.199.199)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dbName)));
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

No TSN nor DSN required.